# How to check the total number of token holders in Etherscan?

Tags: etherscan

I would like to see if all the tokens for a book have been bought. The link in Etherscan is [here](https://etherscan.io/token/0xb6b489793d9d4bb9efbad5c3550da1b19c62cbc9#balances). As I can see, there is a total of 1000 tokens but there is only 12 addresses owning those tokens which amount to a total of 85 tokens. Is my understanding correct?

Then I look at the "Token Holders Chart" which shows the owners and 91.5% is for "Other Accounts". What does the other accounts means?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means Etherscan doesn't yet know which address or addresses own the remaining tokens. They keep track of the owners by watching the 'Transfer' events emitted by the smart contract. That's because you cannot simply get a list of token holders reading the smart contract. So if an account owns some tokens but no transfer event was emitted on issuance (for example it may have happened on initialization), it won't show up on Etherscan.

Comment: Is it possible to check if all the tokens have been bought?

Comment: @KikoFernandez, it is technically possible to "shake" the contract, and find who is holding what, by scanning the contract storage and use a trial-error process to get the balances, if it returns a non-zero balance, then you discovered a hidden token holder.

Comment: @KikoFernandez It may be, depending on the contract. But it seems the source code is not available.